# Relaiton between gradiant and directional derivative.

Tags: calculus, optimization

In the optimization class, there was a equation I don't quite get it.

For $f:\mathbf{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, $d\in \mathbf{R^n}$, $d$ is a direction for $f$.

$\lim_{\tau\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+\tau d)-f(x)}{\tau}=\nabla f(x+\tau d)^Td\bigg|_{\tau = 0}=\nabla f(x)^Td$

I don't get what is $\bigg|_{\tau = 0}$ in the equation meant. Is it means after I calculate $\nabla f(x+\tau d)^Td$, then I set $\tau = 0$ ?

If we look into the first and third part, $\lim_{\tau\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+\tau d)-f(x)}{\tau}=\nabla f(x)^Td$

It doesn't make sense. Left hand side should mean the slope of f for direction d, and the right hand side should mean using $\nabla f(x)$ as a slope, and moving toward d. How can these two are the same ?

If you can explain the equation for me thoroughly, it will help me a lot, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure as to what you have there, but as I recall the directional derivative can just be calculated as the dot product of the gradiant and the direction vector

Comment: This video visualizes what is going on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNwHXWApyH4

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\bigg|_{\tau = 0}$ just means evaluate this expression at $\tau=0$.

We have

$$\lim_{\tau\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+\tau d)-f(x)}{\tau}=\nabla f(x+\tau d)^Td\bigg|_{\tau = 0}=\nabla f(x+0\cdot d)^Td=\nabla f(x)^Td$$

This expression makes sense, if we want to see how much we are changing in the direction $d$, we look at how the function changes overall $\nabla f(x)$ and then we see how much this vector points in the direction $d$, which is simply the inner product.

Comment: Thanks for the video, in that video u vector has to be unit vector, if so, I can get why the equation is correct. At my class, my professor didn't state that d should be unit vector I guess. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes but the difference between unit vector and regular vector is just a scaling. So we are still taking the projection but we are also scaling it by a factor related to how big $\|d\|$ is.